# Recursion with List Comprehension

Tags: python, recursion, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve a recursion problem for listing all of permutation given the string and its length. So, I have this solution

```
def bit_str(n, s):
    if n == 1:
        return s

    return [digit + bits for digit in bit_str(1, s) for bits in bit_str(n-1, s)]
```

If the input is `bit_str(3, 'abc')`, the result will be `['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']`

Could anyone tell me what is happening in the return statement? I'm a little bit confused with the list comprehension part.

Comment: I suggest you break it down on your own and try to figure out what this does. You could take the input and follow the code one step at a time. If there is something specific that you don't understand, then fell free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: _"Could anyone tell me what is happen in the return statement? I'm a little bit confused with the list comprehension part."_ Why don't you write your solution without list comprehension - just get it doing what you need it to do and later we can figure out how to write the the code using list comprehension.

Comment: BTW, that code is rather inefficient. At a given recursion depth, the same `bit_str(n-1, s)` list gets recalculated on each iteration of the outer `for` loop. So that list should be calculated outside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension

```
a = [b for b in c]
```

is equivalent to

```
a=[]
for b in c :
    a.append(b)
```

So this:

```
a=[digit + bits for digit in bit_str(1, s) for bits in bit_str(n-1, s)]
```

would be the same as

```
a=[]
for bits in bit_str(n-1,s):
    for digit in bit_str(1,s):
        a.append(digit+bits)
```

Demo:

```
def bit_str(n, s):
    if n == 1:
        return s
    return [digit + bits for digit in bit_str(1, s) for bits in bit_str(n-1, s)]

def bit_str2(n, s):
    if(n==1):
        return s
    a=[]
    for digit in bit_str2(1,s) :
        for bits in bit_str2(n-1,s) :
            a.append(digit+bits)
    return a

print bit_str(3,'abc')
print bit_str2(3, 'abc')
```

Output:

```
$ python p.py 
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: Erroneous parentheses for `for` loops.

Comment: @aaron Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @klutt thanks for your explanation. I have tried to break it down like you did and get this result `['aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'ab', 'bb', 'cb', 'ac', 'bc', 'cc']`. So, what make me confuse now is where the recursion happen. Because the function return a list instead of calling the function itself

Comment: Well, the recursion happens each time the function all itself, which it does twice.

Comment: Cool, I got it now. Thanks for your help @klutt